# homomorphisms of finitely generated abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $A$ and $B$ are finitely generated abelian groups such that $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(A,B)\neq0$ and $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(B,A)=0$, I want to prove that $B \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}=0$ and $A \otimes _{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q} \neq 0$.I can see that the statement is true for some finitely generated abelian groups for example when $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ but why it is true in general? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I find this an interesting question; please, add your thoughts about it.

Comment: I can see the statement true for some $A$ and $B$ e.g if I take $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $B= \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ but I don't understand why it is true in general.

Comment: Please, edit your question, adding those thoughts and everything else you attempted. I'm confident the question will be reopened.

Comment: I have an answer. Can't the question be reopened?

Comment: @Bernard I have one too, I was submitting it when the question was closed. Vote for reopening

Comment: @egreg:I don't see where to do that.

Comment: @Bernard Not enough reputation, I guess.

Comment: @user135582 Without an edit from you, the question will never be reopened.

Comment: Short answer: $A\ne0$; $B$ must be torsion; if $A$ is torsion, then $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)\ne0$ implies $\mathrm{Hom}(B,A)\ne0$ (reasoning on $p$-components). So $A$ has a nonzero torsionfree part.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!